# Rotating List which Automatically Updates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, office365

I'm wondering if there's a way to make my Excel holiday rotation list automatically continue when the year is updated. I've searched for a while and found other "rotation" question threads but none that specifically address my question. I do not want to use VBA if at all possible.

[Example Image of What I'd Like to Accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk1cQ.png)

What I would like to see is this:

1. Cell I4 is manually updated to the next Calendar Year (which automatically updates lots of things elsewhere in the book), for example to 2020.
2. When that is updated, cell S4 updates to "2020" and the corresponding holiday list becomes "Labor Day, Thanksgiving Day, Christmas Day..." etc.
3. Cell X4 automatically changes from 2024 to now show the next year in the sequence, 2025. It's corresponding holiday rotation becomes "Thanksgiving Day, Christmas Day, New Year's Day, Memorial Day, Independence Day, Labor Day" automatically.

I basically want the current year to always show in column S, the holiday rotation to shift to the left one column, and then the X column values show what the next sequential year and the holidays in X to become what column S had shown previously. I hope that makes sense.

I know how to get the years in cells S4:X4 to update automatically based on the value entered into I4.

The part I'm struggling with is how to get the list of holidays to continue the rotation when the Year is updated.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Please let me know if clarification is needed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a table listing the holidays in order, starting with New Year's (in my case, this was done in cells `AA4:AA9`
2. Use the following formula in `S4`:

   ```
   =INDEX($AA$4:$AA$9,MOD(S$3-MATCH($R4,$R$4:$R$9),6)+1)
   ```
3. Populate that formula in the entire table